# Python - filtration for 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've created a program that can define maximum, minimum and average temperature of 12 months, but I want to extend it by finding months with the hottest and coldest average temperature. My current code is:

```
def main():

    months = [ ["January", 6,3],
               ["February", 7,3],
               ["March", 10,4],
               ["April", 13,6],
               ["May", 17,9],
               ["June", 20,12],
               ["July", 22,14],
               ["August", 21,14],
               ["September",19,12],
               ["October", 14,9],
               ["November", 10,6],
               ["December", 7,3] ]
    
    
    for month in months:
        month_name = month[0]
        temp = month[1:]
        
        minTemp = min(temp)
        avgTemp = sum(temp)/len(temp)
        maxTemp = max(temp)

        print (month_name, minTemp, avgTemp, maxTemp)


    
    
main()
```

I want to add something like "if `month_name` have the maximum avg temperature, print `month_name` and its temperatures. Also if `month_name` have the minimum avg temperature, print `month_name` and its temperatures

Comment: `max(((m[1]+m[2])/2, m[0]) for m in months)` => `(18.0, 'July')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math
def main():

    months = [ ["January", 6,3],
               ["February", 7,3],
               ["March", 10,4],
               ["April", 13,6],
               ["May", 17,9],
               ["June", 20,12],
               ["July", 22,14],
               ["August", 21,14],
               ["September",19,12],
               ["October", 14,9],
               ["November", 10,6],
               ["December", 7,3] ]
    
    mn,mx=math.inf, -math.inf
    mx_month=["",0]
    mn_month=["",0]
    for month in months:
        month_name = month[0]
        temp = month[1:]
        
        minTemp = min(temp)
        avgTemp = sum(temp)/len(temp)
        maxTemp = max(temp)
        if avgTemp<mn:
            mn_month[0],mn_month[1]=month_name,avgTemp
            mn=avgTemp
        if avgTemp>mx:
            mx_month[0],mx_month[1]=month_name,avgTemp
            mx=avgTemp
        print (month_name, minTemp, avgTemp, avgTemp)

    print("Min avg temo month and temp: ",mn_month)
    print("Max avg temo month and temp: ",mx_month)
    
    
main()
```

Comment: Yes! That works and it's clear and understandable! Thank you so much)!

Answer (score 0):

Append the avg to each month and find min/max

```
months = [["January", 6, 3],
          ["February", 7, 3],
          ["March", 10, 4],
          ["April", 13, 6],
          ["May", 17, 9],
          ["June", 20, 12],
          ["July", 22, 14],
          ["August", 21, 14],
          ["September", 19, 12],
          ["October", 14, 9],
          ["November", 10, 6],
          ["December", 7, 3]]
for m in months:
    m.append((m[1] + m[2]) / 2)

_min_avg = min(months, key = lambda k: k[3])
_max_avg = max(months, key = lambda k: k[3])
print(_min_avg)
print(_max_avg)
```

Comment: you make him change his list, which may needed elsewhere

Comment: @DanielMeltzer - I am adding an item to the data of each month. I do not modify the data.